# Monotouch: Understand Foundation Attributes

Tags: attributes, xamarin.ios

Could you explain me the following attributes?

1) `[MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("SomeClass")]`

Is this attribute is used only for register classes with IB? Do I have to use this class when I extend an iOS class programatically?

2) `[Export("initSomething")]`

When do I have to use this attribute? For selector, ok. Anything else?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute on a class exposes the class to the Objective-C world.   You need that if you want to call methods in that class.   The name passed to register will be the name that the Objective-C world uses for your class.

Export is used to expose a single method or property to that world.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Could you explain me in more detail what "You need that if you want to call methods in that class"?

Comment: What it's not very clear for me is the following. When I create a class, which extends an iOS class (for example UIViewController), and there I create some methods, those methods are not exposed to that world with attributes. Why? Thank you again.